# How do I fix my graph?

Tags: graphs

So I'm trying to center this graph right underneath the small paragraph shown in the image. For the graph, I'm trying to have both axes have the same scaling and my domain and range don't work. For some reason, I can't seem to move the legend in the right spot either. Would appreciate a bit of help!

```
\documentclass{article}
When studying the surface itself, these results cohere with its symmetrical properties; Through projection upon the $xy$plane, the surface's footprint is defined as a two dimensional semi-circle with the equation $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{center}
    
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel = \(x\),
    ylabel = {\(y\)},
]    
%Below the red parabola is defined
\addplot [
    y=-0.25:2,
    domain=-2:2, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{(1-x^2)^0.5};
\addlegendentry{\(x^2 - 2x - 1\)}
legend pos: northwest

\end{axis}
\end{center}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Overleaf is just editor. It has nothing common with your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Your environment `center` is on the wrong place. In it had to be complete picture not just `axis` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
                
\begin{document}
When studying the surface itself, these results cohere with its symmetrical properties; Through projection upon the $xy$plane, the surface's footprint is defined as a two dimensional semi-circle with the equation $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel = \(x\),
    ylabel = {\(y\)},
]

%Below the red parabola is defined
\addplot [
    y=-0.25:2,
    domain=-2:2,
    samples=100,
    color=red,
]
{(1-x^2)^0.5};
\addlegendentry{\(x^2 - 2x - 1\)}
legend pos: northwest
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Axis options are usually collected in its preamble nod be a part of image body. So complete image should be:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel = \(x\),
    ylabel = {\(y\)},
    enlargelimits=0.2,
    legend pos=north east
]
\addplot [
    domain=-1:1,
    samples=100,
    color=red,
]
{(1-x^2)^0.5};
\legend{\(x^2 - 2x - 1\)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

However, you may insert your image in the float `figure` environment as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
                
\begin{document}
When studying the surface itself, these results cohere with its symmetrical properties; Through projection upon the $xy$plane, the surface's footprint is defined as a two dimensional semi-circle with the equation $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
...
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\caption{My image}
\label{fig:ilustration}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Alright works perfectly now thanks!

Comment: @KouroshHashemi, here is policy that instead saying "thank you", you upvote answer, which you liked and even accept it (so far you not accept any answer on your questions) by clicking on up triangle  and check mark at top left side of answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your `tikzpicture` inside `figure` environment.

Just like that

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2,3);
        \draw[<->] (0,3.1) -- (0,0) -- (2.1,0);
        \draw[green,fill=yellow] (1,1) circle [radius=0.5];
        \draw[red] (0,0) -- (0,1);
        \draw[red] (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (2,3);
        \draw[domain=-1:2] plot (\x, \x*\x + 2);
        \node[below] at (1,1) {\tiny Text $R=0,5$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{TikZ centered}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Yes, but it's better to use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}...\end{center}` in floating environment, to avoid the addition of extra (spurious) vertical space.